# Selecting most frequent combinations while removing the parts of that combination R

Tags: r, combinations, frequency

I have a dataset with combinations and their frequency as shown below in an example. The idea is to find all combinations (every name has to be used) to have the highest possible value for count (frequency).

| Person 1 | Person 2 | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 4 |
| A | D | 4 |
| A | C | 3 |
| B | C | 2 |
| C | D | 1 |
| B | D | 0 |

A, B, C and D are names of people and count is the frequency of a combination of two people.
In this example the highest count can be reached by having an AD and BC combination, which sums to 6 (4+2). If we take AB and CD as a combination the total sum of count will be lower (5, 4+1).

I would like to have a dataset looking like this as an answer:

| Person 1 | Person 2 | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | D | 4 |
| B | C | 2 |

How can I create this dataset from the original without having duplicate names and with having the highest possible count. So if there is an AD combination, there can not be another combination including A or D.

I tried following code, but this does not give me the desired dataset:

```
dat <- data %>%
  arrange(desc(count))
count = 0
while (nrow(dat)>0){
  print(dat[1,])
  dat <- dat %>%
  filter(!(X1==X1[1]|X1==X2[1]|X2==X1[1]|X2==X2[1]))
}
```

dat is the arranged dataset shown in the first table. I print the first row with the highest count and delete all combinations that has one of the names in their combination (because I can use a name only once). This is looped until there are no more people left.

This code will give following dataset:

| Person 1 | Person 2 | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 4 |
| C | D | 1 |

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a more elegant solution with `igraph`, but here is my approach:

Using your data

```
your_data <- tibble::tribble( ~Person.1, ~Person.2, ~Count, "A", "B", 4L, "A", "D", 4L, "A", "C", 3L, "B", "C", 2L, "C", "D", 1L, "B", "D", 0L)
```

and *assuming `Person.1` and `Person.2` are in alphabetical order*, you can do

```
library(purrr)

with(your_data, unique(c(Person.1, Person.2))) %>%
  combinat::permn(\(x) split(x, (seq_along(x) + 1) %/% 2) %>%
                         map(sort) %>%
                         map_dfr(set_names, c("Person.1", "Person.2"))) %>%
  map(~ arrange(.x, Person.1)) %>%
  unique() %>%
  imap(~ dplyr::left_join(.x, your_data)) %>%
  rlist::list.sort((sum(Count))) %>%
  first()
```

returning the desired

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  Person.1 Person.2 Count
  <chr>    <chr>    <int>
1 A        D            4
2 B        C            2
```

Comment: Does this still work with 6, 8 or more people, because I just tested it with 6 people and I have a dataset with only two combinations instead of three as an answer. Thank you for answering by the way

Comment: I think I figured it out, but the problem is that I have around 30 different people  so there are a lot of combinations. Is there a way to do it more automatically (without having to merge 30 datasets and to add 30 different scores and so on?)

Comment: I agree that this requires a more structured approach. Is it always pairs of two?

Comment: Yes, it is always pairs of two, but every person is paired with every other person (so combination of 30 people). This results in a dataset of every possible pair with their count/frequency. And from this dataset I need the dataset where there are only 15 pairs left (using every person) with the highest count sum.

Comment: Are they always in alphabetical oder across the columns?

Comment: Not at the moment, but I can change them to be in alphabetic order

Comment: I updated my answer to a generalized method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234141/discussion-between-joran-de-bock-and-ktiu).